# How to have a transparent ImageButton: Android

Tags: android, transparent, imagebutton, surfaceview

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/previous"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/media_skip_backward"
android:background="@drawable/transparent"></ImageButton>
```

This is what I tried to get a transparent ImageButton so as to place those buttons on a SurfaceView. But Eclipse, gives me an error in the project as soon as I include the transparent line in xml.

Please help.

Comment: just a side note: instead of your own transparent image, you could generally also just use @android:color/transparent - no need for your own custom transparent image

Comment: Please note that by giving the image button a transparent background, you're removing a visual feedback for button clicked (and probably disabled) state. This results in a slight decrease of usability.

Comment: In order to be sure that the ImageButton actually gets placed upon the SurfaceView it is also useful to call previousButton.bringToFront(), otherwise it may still be hidden behind the SurfaceView

Comment: The Android API provides the correct attribute to create a transparent background without losing the visual feedback for button clicked or for the other states! Read my answer below!

Answer (score 1069, accepted):

Try using null for the background ...

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Thank you.
This works. Only the image is seen and not the box around it. But can I lay this button over the SurfacaView ie over the video preview? Is this possible? How do I do it?

Comment: @Namratha The `SurfaceView` should allow you to blace your buttons over a surface but note: "This can be used to place overlays such as buttons on top of the Surface, though note however that it can have an impact on performance since a full alpha-blended composite will be performed each time the Surface changes." from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: It's not correct to use a null background!! 
The Android API provides the correct attribute to create a transparent background without losing the visual feedback for button clicked or for the other states! Read my answer below!

Comment: Setting the button background to null is not good idea, as mentioned above and below. Answers with using appropriate attributes is a lot better, or create correct selector with transparent for non-clicked and appropriate feedback when clicked.

Comment: That gave me an error.. But this worked for me android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 371):

**DON'T USE A TRANSAPENT OR NULL LAYOUT** because then the button (or the generic view) will no more highlight at click!!!

> I had the same problem and finally **I found the correct attribute from Android API** to solve the problem. It can apply to any view.

Use this in the button specifications:

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: This requires API 11 - you eliminate 24% of the phones in the wild (as of Jan 2014)

Comment: It seems that using the Support library, the API>=11 requirement might be overcome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714682/android-apply-selectableitembackground-in-xml-with-support-v7

Comment: For a round ripple effect, use `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: Luckily as of 2019, this eliminates roughly 0% of the phones in the wild.

Comment: This is better than the top Answer of Quentin?

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 145):

You can also use a transparent color:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: @Geykel, @Adam, you should be aware that this attribute is quite dangerous when used unconditionally since it will add another transparent layer that will get drawn to the screen and might result in overdrawn pixels and slow your application. 

In order to test it, you can use the `Developer option: Show GPU overdraw` and see the difference between setting a background to `@null` and `@android:color/transparent`.

Comment: This is the best and most effective answer. :)

Answer (score 122):

Setting the background to `"@null"` will make the button have no effect when clicked. This will be a better choice.

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Later I found that using

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

is also a good solution. And you can inherit this attribute in your own style.

Comment: didnt work for me and the second one made the app to crash. Perhaps i did smth wrong but i dont know what.

Comment: Requires API level 11. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackground)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also using AppCompact, with this answer the ripple effect works perfectly and on api 19 the normal pressed effect works out of the box.
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Brilliant!

Comment: This solution of `selectableItemBackground` has an added benefit of making the button change states when clicked.  The other solutions make the button appear not clickable.

Answer (score 14):

in run time, you can use following code

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Comment: btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); Works on all API levels

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated use setbackGroundColor as suggested above by AlBeebe

Comment: this method is now deprecated

Answer (score 12):

Don't use null or transparent if you need a click animation. Better:

```
//Rectangular click animation
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

//Rounded click animation
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe the accepted answer should be:

`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

This is the same as @lory105's answer but it uses the support library for maximum compatibility (the `android:` equivalent is only available for API >= 11)

Answer (score 8):

Remove this line :

```
android:background="@drawable/transparent">
```

And in your activity class set

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.previous);
btn.setAlpha(100);
```

You can set alpha level 0 to 255

o means transparent and 255 means opaque.

Comment: But does this enable the button to lie on top of the SurfaceView?

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading as it makes the entire button semi-opaque. If wishing to do this from code then pass null to the setBackground method. setAlpha is not what you need.

Comment: It makes the whole view transparent.

Answer (score 5):

**The best way is using the transparent color code**

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

use the color code #00000000 for making any thing transparent

Comment: `@android:color/transparent` without hard-coded values.

Comment: No, referenced values should be preferred...but IMO, @Fred, even putting an `@android:` reference directly in layout is considered an hardcoded value since if you want to change it you still have to surf in the layout to find it. I would declare something like this `<item name="something">@android:color/transparent</item>` and use my own value in layout so I can easily find it in my ***resources.xml*** file and change it without having to search it in layout

Answer (score 2):

Use `ImageView`... it have transparent background by default...

Comment: You can use an ImageView as a button. In your java code you just say ImageView previous = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previous); and then previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{public void onClick(/*this happens when you touch the ImageView*/)}); Voila!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/back"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@null"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:src="@drawable/backbtn" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I was already adding something to the background so , This thing worked for me:

```
   android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

(Android Studio 3.4.1)

**EDIT**: only works on android api level 21 and above. for compatibility, use this instead

```
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code works just fine by setting the background to transparent:

```
<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/previous"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/media_skip_backward"
android:background="transparent"></ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the background of the ImageButton as @null in XML

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/previous"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/media_skip_backward"
android:background="@null"></ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **"@null"** . It worked for me.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bkash"
    android:id="@+id/bid1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works and also keeps visual feedback for button clicked,

```
android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either use: `android:background="#00000000"` or `android:backgroundTint="#00000000"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Programmatically** it can be done by :

```
image_button.setAlpha(0f) // to make it full transparent
image_button.setAlpha(0.5f) // to make it half transparent
image_button.setAlpha(0.6f) // to make it (40%) transparent
image_button.setAlpha(1f) // to make it opaque
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this appears to make the entire image transparent, not just the background.

Comment: @threed I know, and that's exactly the OP asking in his ques, "a transparent ImageButton".

Comment: You're absolutely right, the OP asked for a transparent button. But his example suggests that he might have meant to ask for a button with a transparent background (e.g. `android:background="@drawable/transparent"`). Either way, I'm just suggesting a possible reason for the downvote; I'm not saying it's justified.

Comment: @threed well, may be that was the reason for it, thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

This is  programatically set background color as transparent

```
 ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
 btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a `.xml` use the below code:

```
android:background="@null"
```

And, here is an example of doing it programmatically

```
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add padding, it helps to show button effect. Add padding to adjust with this background.

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:padding="5dp"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/media_skip_backward">
</ImageButton>
```

I used a transparent `png` for the `ImageButton`, and the `ImageButton` worked.

Comment: This is not a good solution.. use the right attribute provided by the Android API! Read my answare.

Comment: This will result in another layer, adding to overdraw.