# android meaning of @null in xml attribute

Tags: android-layout

I found the following attribute in one xml layout:

```
android:background="@null"
```

What is the meaning of `@null`? What is the difference between specifying background="@null" and omitting background attribute?

Comment: Here is a nice explanation for you query. [Android Developer Blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html) [How to have a transparent ImageButton: Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402787/how-to-have-a-transparent-imagebutton-android) These two links will surely clear your query.

Comment: Reading the first link requires patience but it was worth it. DO READ IT.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If I remember correctly, omitting the background attribute sets a default background. However, explicitly setting background to "@null" removes the background, causing whatever is below the element to be shown. In particular, if you for instance set the background of a Button to null, the border of the button will also be gone (and the button effectively will not really look like a button at all).

Answer (score 7):

What i have observed if i do **`android:background="@null"`or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` both have same effect**, they just remove the background of the view, so you will see the background colour of the view which is beneath this view.

Comment: For me @android:color/transparent is working ok, the other one: android:background="@null" is throwing an error, I'm using a constraint layout as a container. Thanks!

Comment: Ripple shape also different when using @null or transport.