# Compiler is showing this "error: failed linking file resources."

Tags: android, android-layout

Compiler is showing Error in these lines: I can't seems to locate the problem kindly help me.

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_magnify"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:textSize="15sp"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:id="@+id/input_search"
     android:background="null"
     android:hint="Enter Address, City or Zip Code"
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch"  />
```

Comment: please provide more context to understand your problem

Comment: if you don't want any background, why put `android:background="null"` in first place?

Comment: @Sam. `@null` actually performs a little bit differently. I've never had a reason to use it, it's [a little confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7594814/608312).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:background="null"` doesn't mean anything. You need to use `android:background="@null"`.

In the future showing your actual error (likely something similar to the error below) will help people actually be able to help you, instead of guessing.

```
fragment_dashboard.xml:219: error: 'null' is incompatible with attribute background (attr) reference|color
```