# Is it possible to "look" through a view onto the parent without transparency?

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency, layer, mask

is it possible to look a view/a stack of views to its parent view, as if I would directly look onto it?

I mean, not just getting the parent view as an image and setting it onto the top layer. Imagine, the parent one is partial transparent, and I also want to see this transparency.

The reason why I´m asking you can see on the picture above.

I basically want to have a modifyable mask as a toplayer, which allows me to set corner radius at runtime, affecting the complete view of all layouts together but without modifying each one.

I want to transfer the direct view onto the parent to the top layer.

Is there any possibility to do that?
[image]
http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/379/layoutsm.png

Comment: Have You tried to apply the following way http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638271/657487 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Or as Hissain mentioned, you can try

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Reference for more info
[How to have a transparent ImageButton: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402787/how-to-have-a-transparent-imagebutton-android)

Answer (score 0):

With FrameLayout you can try to set background for all views you want to make transparent like these,

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```