# Making beneath image by dragging a circle over it in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my implementation, I have two images, one layed over the other. As, I move a circle object over the top image, I want to make that area inside circle transperent, so that I can see the beneath image. For example I have two images - a car image and its framework image. I overlay car image over framweork image and as i drag a circle over car image, it should show the beneath framework.

I tried to search a lot but not getting any pointers. Somewhere I read that I need to use alpha masking or image masking using porterduff and xfermode. but I did not understand.

Specifically,

How can I make the above image transperent and how can I only make the area inside circle transperent?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used helpful inputs from the question [PorterduffXfermode: Clear a section of a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337679/porterduffxfermode-clear-a-section-of-a-bitmap). In the example below, touch area becomes 'transparent' and it's possible to observe `down_image` part beneath `up_image` (both images are just jpg drawables in resources).

Basically there's two possible implementations:

1. Disabling hardware acceleration of drawing which would make `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` to make view transparent (refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) for more details about hardware acceleration effects):

   **Activity:**

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {
       /** Overlay image */
       private DrawingView mDrawingView = null;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

           final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

           // Create the view for the xfermode test
           mDrawingView = new DrawingView(this);

           params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
           mDrawingView.setLayoutParams(params);

           final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

           relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_image);
           relativeLayout.addView(mDrawingView);

           // Main part of the implementation - make layer drawing software
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
               mDrawingView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
           }

           // Show the layout with the test view
           setContentView(relativeLayout);
       }
   }
   ```

   **DrawingView:**

   ```
   /**
    * View which makes touch area transparent
    */
   public class DrawingView extends View {
       /**  Paint to clear touch area */
       private Paint mClearPaint = null;
       /** Main bitmap */
       private Bitmap mBitmap = null;

       /** X coordinate of touch circle */
       private int mXTouch = -1;
       /** Y coordinate of touch circle */
       private int mYTouch = -1;
       /** Radius of touch circle */
       private int mRadius = 0;

       /**
        * Default constructor
        *
        * @param ct {@link Context}
        */
       public DrawingView(final Context ct) {
           super(ct);

           // Generate bitmap used for background
           mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ct.getResources(), R.drawable.up_image);

           // Generate array of paints
           mClearPaint = new Paint();
           mClearPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 0);
           mClearPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
           mClearPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

           // Set all transfer modes
           mClearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

           mRadius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radius);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDraw(final Canvas canv) {
           // Background colour for canvas
           canv.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));

           // Draw the bitmap leaving small outside border to see background
           canv.drawBitmap(mBitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight()), null);

           // Loop, draws 4 circles per row, in 4 rows on top of bitmap
           // Drawn in the order of mClearPaint (alphabetical)
           if (mXTouch > 0 && mYTouch > 0) {
               canv.drawCircle(mXTouch, mYTouch, mRadius, mClearPaint);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
           boolean handled = false;

           // get touch event coordinates and make transparent circle from it
           switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   mXTouch = (int) event.getX();
                   mYTouch = (int) event.getY();
                   // TODO: Note, in case of large scene it's better not to use invalidate without rectangle specified
                   invalidate();
                   handled = true;
                   break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                   mXTouch = -1;
                   mYTouch = -1;
                   // TODO: Note, in case of large scene it's better not to use invalidate without rectangle specified
                   invalidate();
                   handled = true;
                   break;

               default:
                   // do nothing
                   break;
           }

           return super.onTouchEvent(event) || handled;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Adopt this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch), but looks like it depends on Android version, because suggested solution hasn't worked on mine 4.2 device at all.