# Adding a View in ViewGroup

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

I am trying to add a View to ViewGroup on ViewGroup's onTouchEvent, following is the code:

```
        ViewGroup mDrawingCanvas = new ViewGroup(mContext) 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isFocused() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, "View's On focused is called !");
                return super.isFocused();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    View vv = new View(mContext);
                    vv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    vv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 200));
                    this.addView(vv);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Views child count = "+this.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;

                    break;

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r,
                    int b) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

The View is being added to the Viewgroup, Toast displays greater View count on every Touch Down Event, but the View is not being displayed on Screen in the ViewGroup.
I have seen related question on StackOverflow, but my question is unique and different.
Please guide me on how to solve this problem, any help is highly appreciated.

**P.S:** I have also tried to set the Layout params of the View before adding it to the ViewGroup, but am getting the same results. I have also printed the View's width and Height in LogCat after adding it to the ViewGroup and it always displays 0. I think that the problem is somewhere with the settings of Width and Height of the View.

Comment: implement onLayout method

Comment: Please elaborate, what implementation should i do in `onLayout(...)` method ?

Comment: just see existing ViewGroup.onLayout. implementations

Comment: here you have FrameLayout http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/FrameLayout.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom `ViewGroup`, you have to implement the `onLayout` method to display anything.

`ViewGroup` is just a base class for other layouts, it does not do anything by itself. I would advise to use one of its descendant, like `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout`.

---

If you are creating a drawing application, you *might* be better using a `Canvas` instead of using a custom layout. `Canvas` already provides several methods to draw lines, circles, rectangles, etc. You will have some work to do if you want to be able to move one element afterwards though.

[Draw with a Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#draw-with-canvas)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!, please share some example code of `onLayout(..)` so that i can customize it :)

Comment: I have tried it, to draw the shapes and other stuff on draw. But i am unable to select or Move the Drawings. There fore i have moved on to this approach. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354776/how-to-move-a-shapedrawable-in-canvas-on-touch-events

Answer (score 0):

You should to define how children views will show in your ViewGroup in onLayout method.
If you don't need some special view, try to use FrameLayout instead ViewGroup

Comment: I am implementing a Drawing Application and i am going to add Line Views, Rect Views, Free Hand Views to this ViewGroup. I am new to drawing stuff in Android, i don't know if i am using the correct approach or not. But, for now, i am planning to take my drawing canvas as a subclass of ViewGroup and planning to add Views of Lines, and other shapes to this View Group.

Comment: Please share some simple implementation code of `onLayout(...)` It will be great deal of help here.