# Individual click events on items in Layer-List Android

Tags: android, colors, android-canvas, layer-list

I am working on an Android application for school.

In this application I want to Draw let's say a pie chart. I don't want to use a library to draw one. 
The application should draw the pie chart (witch a pre-written canvas or something like that).

After that the user can change the colors of the pie chart by selecting the individual parts. 
The selected part must then change color. But a color should not be the same as the part next to it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5DGi.png

Does someone now how to do this?

---

Found solution 
[How to Move a ShapeDrawable in Canvas on Touch Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354776/how-to-move-a-shapedrawable-in-canvas-on-touch-events)

Thanks everyone for help

Comment: "Individual click events on items in Layer-List Android" -- that is not possible, as views, not drawables, are the ones that receive events.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. Isn't there still a possibility that it can still be done with something else than Layer-List?

Comment: Oh, I am sure it can be done, probably using the answer you already have, plus your own logic to interpret the touch events on the different segments of your pie chart. Personally, I would find a library and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing! 
It's sounds like an excellent practice for Canvas using.

define a new canvas (there are plenty of tutorials, here's one - http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/introduction-to-2d-drawing-in-android.html#.U7QE6fnYSZM)

and use this trick ([Android draw circle with 2 colors (Pie chart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731261/android-draw-circle-with-2-colors-pie-chart)) to draw the pies..

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the articles. It's a start but not entirely what i want. I still need an option to change the colors of every object individually.  For example let the user change the green part to red.