# android transparent ImageButton not clickable in MvvmCross

Tags: android, transparency, imagebutton, mvvmcross

How does one create an ImageButton with transparent background that still clickable (still acts like a Button)?

This is the xml snippet:

```
 <ImageButton
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/serverschedule"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/predict"
            local:MvxBind="Click PredictCmd" />
```

I have also tried `android:background="#00000000"`  and  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`and in all cases, I do get the desired visual effect but button no longer can be clicked.

I am using MvvmCross framework to binding to the Click event of the button, hence there is no code behind.

I am testing against API Level 15, if this matters.

**EDIT**  Added entire axml for button.
**EDIT**  Adding MVVM framework as it may have something to do with problem.

TIA.

Comment: Provide desired width and height of button.

Comment: your Button has no `layout_width` and `layout_height`. Also, are you shure that you apply a `View.OnCliclListener` to it?

Comment: @RafaelT, the only thing I am changing is the background color.  I have another button besides this one that works fine with similar layout except I am not nullifying the background color.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your problem correctly. The button is correctly shown, the `OnClickListener` works but the button does not have "touch feedback" (http://developer.android.com/design/style/touch-feedback.html)?

Comment: @rubenlop88, the button is correctly shown with transparent background image but the OnClickListener is not invokved.  Please note that I am using an MVVM framework so maybe the problem lies there.

Comment: Ok, then any of the answers below may work. Your `ImageButton` should have an `id` and you should attach a `OnClickListener` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of the suggestions.

This is what finally worked for me:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Based on responses from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402787/how-to-have-a-transparent-imagebutton-android?lq=1) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide width and height of your button.

Also try this :

```
ImageButton theButton = (ImageButton )findViewById(R.id.theButton);
theButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
theButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

theButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{   
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
    // DO STUFF
 }
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do certain Necessary changes

```
<ImageButton
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/serverschedule"
                android:background="@null"
                android:id="@+id/mybutton"
</ImageButton
```

Into Your code:

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Your Stuff here
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/timeText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="image button"
    android:src="@drawable/anchor" />
```

set clickable attribute to true, and handle onclick event in your activity like

```
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: setting clickable to true does not help.  Maybe a problem with the framework I am using.

Answer (score 0):

No change in your xml file..  even no need to add this `android:clickable="true"`

edit your java file as below code...

```
ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
 }
```

If this doesn't work you might have problem with your parent layout.   Please post that if so....

Answer (score 0):

what's the meaning of the "acts as a button" ?  when you use

```
android:background="@null"
```

your ImageButton will have no background and you can use selector as the src ,you'll get the same acts as a button,also can click as usual
selector like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>      
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>  
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>  
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"/>  
</selector>
```

also see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402787/how-to-have-a-transparent-imagebutton-android?rq=1)

Comment: using android:background="@null" is one option to set a transparent background as I understand. Other options to make background transparent result to same effect.  I do not intend to change the button's behavior, just the look.  So do not expect to be changing selectors and such.

Answer (score 0):

```
back.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

works for all android versions