# selectableItemBackground crashing App

Tags: android

i'm trying to make ImageButton using 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` but my app crashed. I just following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537061/1533670) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714682/android-apply-selectableitembackground-in-xml-with-support-v7). Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

**activity.xml**

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/signUp"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"

    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

    android:src="@drawable/sign_up"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_sign_up"        
    />
```

**Log Cat**

```
05-31 18:50:24.077: W/dalvikvm(28619): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d0b2a0)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh/yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.WelcomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:19)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    ... 11 more
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    ... 24 more
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010015 a=-1}
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3449)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
05-31 18:50:24.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28619):    ... 27 more
```

Comment: may be you have just paste android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" you also have to import support v7 as library. as described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714682/android-apply-selectableitembackground-in-xml-with-support-v7/19780767#19780767

Comment: replace `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
` with `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @RaviKant i have imported appcompat v7 in project, my MainActivity using appcompat v7, so should i import appcompat v7 in activity.java too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@Gopal Gopi is correct. If you have the appcompat v7 imported properly into your project, use this for android:background in your xml:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Also, make sure that whatever item you use this on has `android:clickable="true"`

Good luck!

Comment: That's incorrect. You can only use the native attribute ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground in Android 4 and above. With AppCompat you need to use ?attr/selectableItemBackground in combination with an AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 3):

To make it work you should use AppCompact base theme in your App or Activity. Like following:

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Turning a comment on the question, by Gopal Gopi, [selectableItemBackground crashing App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969769/selectableitembackground-crashing-app/77677470#comment36930896_23969769), into an answer:)
Replacing
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`
by
`android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
can help.

Comment: Note, turning a comment into an answer which covers a new aspect is fine. You should however correctly refer to the source. I mean, you did not want to just comment and say thanks for it, did you? Because then please understand https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead, i.e. that you should instead wait for your privileges to comment for commenting. Also that "Thanks" alone is not the idea of StackOverflow. For formatting, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I guess you are unable to add some explanation of the effect of this change and how it helps to solve the problem described at the top of this page. But if you do, your post would probably be better received. Without you might find that Gopal Gopi has a reason for using a comment instead of an answer post for just dropping an unexplained code-only solution. By the way, if you now also wish you had not created an answer, you can just delete this.