# Snackbar InflateException in Design Support Library 22.2.1

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, appcompatactivity, android-snackbar, snackbar

I'm trying to use the Snackbar from the Design Support Library 22.2.1 and I'm getting an `InflateException`.

This is how I'm using it:

```
Snackbar.make(searchQueryButton, "Hello world", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And this is the exception:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.android.search.test_app/com.myapp.android.search.test_app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:127)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:148)
            at com.myapp.android.search.test_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:127)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:148)
            at com.myapp.android.search.test_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class TextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout.<init>(Snackbar.java:534)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:127)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:148)
            at com.myapp.android.search.test_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:747)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3742)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:637)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:632)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:44)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:40)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:806)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:836)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout.<init>(Snackbar.java:534)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:127)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:148)
            at com.myapp.android.search.test_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is this an issue from the library?

BTW, I'm running it on Lollipop 5.1 and I have all my activities extending from `AppCompatActivity` with the proper theme.

**EDIT:**

I realised that the theme is the problem. If I make my activity use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, it works as expected.

However, if I use my own theme (which overrides `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`), it throws the exception I described above.

This is my theme:

```
    <style name="Theme.MLTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>

        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/gray_dark</item>

        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.MLTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MLTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.MLTheme.ActionBar.TabView</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.MLTheme.ActionBar.TabText</item>

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MLButton.Primary</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MLButton.Primary</item>

        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/textview_default</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.MyApp.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyleLarge">@style/Widget.MyApp.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:scrollViewStyle">@style/Widget.ScrollView.Default</item>

        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>

        <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/selection_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/selection_color</item>

        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MLSpinnerItem</item>

        <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/MLPreference.ListHeader</item>

        <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/MLDropDownItemStyle</item>

        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        <!-- for native ActionBar -->
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>

        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>

    </style>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I found that if I remove the last entry in my theme, everything works as expected again.

<s>`<item name="selectableItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>`</s>

Does anyone know why this is causing the exception? And also, does anyone know how to replace that entry to achieve the same effect by keeping the Snackbar working?

Thank you.

Comment: It'd be useful to see your XML, since ` XML file line #18: Error`

Comment: Are you using that attribute on your snackbar? It would be easier if you post the view xml. In the meantime, you might want to check some similar questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969769/selectableitembackground-crashing-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved the issue by changing this:

`<item name="selectableItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>`

... to this:

`<item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>`

I suspect that if you upgrade AppCompat to 22.2.1, you also have to change that attribute.