# How to remove RadioButton circle in Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a custom RadioButton that looks as follow in a Android 5.0 device.

[image]

These *RadioButtons* are dynamic created as shown in the follow methods. So the first method *redioButtonPresenterApparence* sets its appearance removing circle (setting *buttonDrwable* to *null*. The second method set the buttons background later.

```
private void radioButtonPresenterApparence(RadioButton presenter, int icon) {
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icon);
    presenter.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
    presenter.setButtonDrawable(null);
    presenter.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}

private void updateButtonsBackground(){
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    BackgroundSelector bgSelector = new BackgroundSelector(childCount);
    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
        View rb = getChildAt(i);
        rb.setBackgroundResource( bgSelector.getBackgroundResource(i) );
        rb.requestLayout();
    }

    requestLayout();
}
```

My problem is when testing the same on Samsung Android 4.4.4 devices (not sure about other manufactories), it shows as follow.

[image]

**PS:** It's a code created RadioButton. You can check it in the follow method:

```
private void addPresenter(int icon){
    RadioButton presenter = new RadioButton(getContext());  //Create new RadioButton
    radioButtonPresenterApparence(presenter, icon);         //Set icon and configure aparence
    addView(presenter);                                     //Add new button to Selector
    presenterParentAparance(presenter);                     //Config button inside parent
    requestLayout();                                        //Request layout update to Selector
}
```

Comment: Google for "android custom radiobutton"

Comment: try putting android:button="@null" in your xml and run

Comment: @AnuragPandit I'm already doing it by `presenter.setButtonDrawable(null)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Find your radio buttons in layout.xml and give them this:

```
android:button="@null"
```

This should do the same thing as `presenter.setButtonDrawable(null);`
 
Except that this actually works

**Edit:**

In case of code created button, please use:

```
presenter.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
```

Actually helps as it is an equivalent of

```
android:button="@null"
```

Comment: It isn't a inflated layout. It's code created. I'll add it into the question.

Comment: In that case, try this:
`presenter.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());`
This is the equivalent of `android:button="@null"`

Comment: Could you add it into your answer, Than I will accept it. Worked just as expected when using `new StateListDrawable()` instead of `null`

Answer (score 4):

AppCompatRadioButton can hide the circle button for API<21, there is needed just declare the following:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
                    android:button="@null"
                    app:buttonCompat="@null" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marijan's answer, I created a `WrappedRadioButton` class that overrides the `setButtonDrawable` methods:

```
class WrappedRadioButton : RadioButton {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
        defStyleAttr: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    @RequiresApi(api = 21)
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    override fun setButtonDrawable(resId: Int) {
        super.setButtonDrawable(StateListDrawable())
    }

    override fun setButtonDrawable(drawable: Drawable?) {
        super.setButtonDrawable(StateListDrawable())
    }
}
```

So whenever I want a RadioButton with `android:button="@null"`, I just use a WrappedRadioButton instead. There's no need to call `setButtonDrawable` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `android:button="?android:selectableItemBackground"`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537061/5093308

Answer (score -2):

setting your custom drawable to radiobutton is staright-forward, you can write something like this programmatically,

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
radioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_custom_drawable);
```